Will "universal" SMPS work at any voltage in the range, even DC?
Is it generally true that switch-mode power supplies with wide input (universal) voltage indicated on the nameplate (say, 100V-240V 50/60Hz) will accept any AC or DC input voltage within the range?
Universal SMPS are obviously designed to work worldwide, and thus will inherently support 110V-120V AC (USA) and 220V-230V AC (Europe). But I want to know if they will generally work just as well at any voltage in-between, say for example 170V AC. I also want to know if DC voltages within the range can generally be assumed to be acceptable as well. Again, generally speaking. If you are asking for datasheets, you are missing the spirit of the question.

You have to give us a link to the datasheet. And there would be no definitive answer.  Some may, some may not.

This question is similar to: Is it possible to power an AC-to-DC switching adapter with a DC input?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can get 12 V car battery to 24 V step-up converters with a regulated output.

@winny Seems this question was due for an update; the one answer there looks outdated (or incomplete), given what the answers have mentioned here. I might vote for the opposite case (close that thread and redirect here); unusual, but a close-as-duplicate doesn't have to be strictly backwards in time :)

Any DC between 50 and 60 Hz will work :-) .  || DC DC would be on a caae by case basis - ask manufacturer or examine circuit.

It would be useful if the CLOSE VOTER explained their vote.

@TimWilliams I see your point. A reverse merger of sorts.

Most likely fine, but, one needs to know the design to confirm.
There are two likely operational exceptions:

The PFC circuit depends on a more-or-less sinusoidal input to operate.  Perhaps it's anticipating the rise and fall over a cycle, perhaps it's tracking the waveform (some sort of PLL thing), who knows.  I haven't personally seen a controller that does this -- or at least, says it does -- but that's not to say it's impossible, and some quite "smart" (read: highly complicated, mess of digital logic, state machines, perhaps even MCU) controllers exist out there; I wouldn't put it outside the realm of possibility that some rely on assumptions like this.
A much more mundane reason (and this I have met examples of): when no more AC is detected, a switch is engaged to discharge the X-capacitors in the input filter, quickly making it safe to touch after unplugging the power cord.

Two common examples of the latter:

The PFC/half-bridge integrated controller has a high-voltage pin on it, to obtain startup current, and as a bonus, they can perform X-cap discharge. Examples include TI UCC256404 and NXP TEA2017AAT/2.
The controller has no such function (or it's unused for other reasons), but a similar function has been implemented, either in discrete circuitry (a charge pump keeping a depletion-MOSFET switch, into a discharge resistor, open), or an integrated device (e.g. Power Integrations CAPZero-2).

The key is that the variation or reversal of the input, or rather lack thereof, is used to trigger the discharge.  Applying DC will burn out the resistors (maybe the problem solves itself, hah), or the IC (a somewhat bigger problem).
If you want to go to the trouble of "fixing" such a supply (or just inspecting it internally to figure out whether it does or not), you'll have to crack it open and see.  This is not very practical for most adapters, which are ultrasonically welded shut.  You may be better off shopping around for an equivalent power supply that is rated for DC input.
Regarding voltage range
If it's a passive rectified unit, it will need closer to the minimum peak voltage at DC.
A lot of small converters, based on regulators like Power Integrations LNK623 (popular in small adapters, "wall warts", standby/auxiliary supplies in electronics, etc.), will actually start up and operate at quite low voltages (sometimes 20-30V); however, they will not reach full output current capacity until design minimum voltage.  This may or may not be useful, so would be a "try and see" option.
(Note that design minimum, may not be the same as minimum rated input voltage.  The latter is based on standards: take the world minimum, minus a tolerance, minus brownout margin.  A design might work to full capacity at say 60V (AC, or DC as the case may be), but be rated 85VAC min because rating it for less just doesn't matter.  All we know from the nameplate, is the design minimum is at least 85VAC.)
Some devices might also run equally well on 85V AC or DC, as the input boost (active PFC) section works just fine at such voltages -- 85V RMS sine, rectified, has a 76V average output.
Regarding safety and reliability
Note that switches and fuses have a much easier time breaking AC than DC.  This is perhaps the strongest reason against doing it -- if the circuit fails to open when the switch does, or when the fuse melts under fault conditions, the arc started can continue to burn, lighting the device on fire, melting the enclosure (it's probably plastic), and so on.
Once a DC arc is started, it can draw current up to the capacity of the source and wiring, and keep on burning, through the enclosure, up wires, into walls, etc.
Even if the source has enough excess current capacity to clear fuses, it can happen that enough wire resistance is present to limit current.  This happens from time to time on AC circuits, too: distribution (even transmission!) lines sometimes develop a huge arc spanning between them (sustained in this case by the high voltage, say 10s kV); the arc might race up and down the street, but not draw enough current to trip the upstream recloser (automated switch/fuse) that would clear it.
Keep in mind, fuses are crude devices: the fault current should be a good, at least 5 or 10 times the nominal amp rating of the circuit, to ensure fuses clear promptly (or at all!).  A system based on fault current opening fuses, should be designed to have that fault current available on even the longest branch.
Current-limited sources, like solar panels, and DC-DC converters with simple fault limiting (as opposed to foldback or hiccup limiting, or latching protection), must provide alternative means for monitoring and protecting branch circuits.
It is possible that a given device has a DC-rated fuse.  Particularly among fast- and ultrafast-blow ceramic-body fuses, DC ratings (at nontrivial voltages i.e. >30V) aren't uncommon; but you generally have to pay extra to get comparable (say 250VDC 1kA+) breaking capacity, so they aren't commonly found in commercial products.
Again, you can only know fusing based on an internal inspection, or by providing suitable external fusing at the device inlet.

If the OP created an "inverter" that produced square-wave AC by simply reversing the polarity of the DC input with MOSFETs switches, would that be a disaster for typical PFC circuits that are expecting sine waves?  (Maybe not perfect square wave, probably you'd want some dead time to avoid shoot-through with both MOSFETs partially conducting.)  (I posted this same comment on Neil's answer.)

Depends. Some controllers monitor the AC line (before rect), some after.  You get very little pulsing after the rectifier that way, with just simple reversal.. But with ~half dead time added, you get a "modified sine wave" which is commonly used in cheap mains inverters; this is much more likely to succeed, and it's even possible that a supply has been tested to operate with one of these.

Most low power universal SMPS use a rectifier direct to a DC bus capacitor, and switch it down from there. This means the power stage is capable of working from DC. I have some 10 W LED 'tubes' that do exactly this, I have tested them on DC, and they work. You may take my sample of one with the suspicion it deserves.
As a designer, I would have no trouble in making such an input require some 'activity' on the input, like AC instead of DC, and preventing it working for DC. I don't know if any low power devices do this. It would be a bit of a mean thing to do to prevent it working in all the ways it could.
A high power universal input SMPS will have a power factor correction (PFC) first stage, before the DC bus capacitor. This is designed to draw current in phase with the input voltage waveform to improve the power factor over what a standard rectifier would provide. It needs to servo its effective input resistance to match the average power being drawn, to keep the DC bus capacitor at the right sort of voltage.
As a designer, I could design a PFC stage to work on DC as well as AC. However, as its raison d'etre is to track the AC input voltage and adjust the current drawn to match, I would not be surprised if something timed-out if presented with a non-changing input voltage. You might be able to identify the smart components in the PFC stage and read the data sheet.
No one can guarantee it will survive if you simply plug it in and try it, but you're free to take that option.
So I'm suspicious that the PFC stage might choose not to work. Depending how hacky you want to be, you could always bypass that stage and feed DC directly onto the DC bus capacitor. The following stage is designed to work from DC, so should just work, unless it has been designed to wait for the PFC to tell it to.

If the OP created an "inverter" that produced square-wave AC by simply reversing the polarity of the DC input with MOSFETs switches, would that be a disaster for typical PFC circuits that are expecting sine waves?  (Maybe not perfect square wave, probably you'd want some dead time to avoid shoot-through with both MOSFETs partially conducting.)

There is one other aspect. Typically there is a bridge rectifier at the input and if the circuit is supplied with AC voltage, the average current and power dissipation is equal in both diode pairs.
If you provide a DC voltage, only one diode pair carries all the current and the other is never conducting. We then have a thermal gradient inside the rectifier.
The rated average current for a bridge rectifier assumes this power split between diode pairs. The DC use capability depends on the safety margin the circuit has and may be an issue at full load.

Thank you for this valuable insight. Seems obvious now, but I'm glad you pointed it out.


Is it generally true that switch-mode power supplies with wide-input
(universal) voltage listed on the nameplate (say, 100V-240V 50/60Hz)
will accept any AC or DC input voltage anywhere within the stated
range?

Probably not.
An external AC voltage of 100 volts will peak at around 141 volts and, the rectified internal DC bus will be around 138 volts with some ripple. In other words, the lowest internal DC bus voltage (when powered by an AC of 100 volts) might be 110 to 130 volts volts.
Powering it with an external DC supply of 100 volts is probably not going to work.

I am hoping that 170V DC will work fine

It probably will.

It really depends on the specific product. It might have a protection relay that is rated for HVAC only - applying HVDC to such a relay will will give you a nasty surprise, the relay can't open due to arcing.

Good point, not to mention the fuse might fail to operate for the same reason!

Thank you for this, I didn't realize SMPS do often contain relays and a relay designed to switch AC may fail when switching DC instead.
